# I have a block of code I am unable to understand it

Tags: javascript

I am adding a JavaScript code block here. I am unable to understand why this is used. If anyone understands this.

```js
_objListofData = _objListofData.reduce(function(item, e1) {
  var matches = item.filter(function(e2) {
    return e1.Code == e2.Code
  });
  if (matches.length == 0) {
    item.push(e1);
  }
  return item;
}, []);
```

Comment: There's no jQuery code there, that's just vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: check [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: I think this is filtering the array so there are no duplicate `Code` properties.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ I think it takes more than just reading the description of `reduce` to understand this, because of the `filter()` code embedded in it. It took me a few minutes to figure out what the complete logic is doing.

Comment: having data would be better to explain things

Comment: The names of the parameters to the reduce callback are inappropriate. The first parameter "item" is definitely wrongly named, which is probably contributing to the OP's confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is use to filter out the distinct result based on Code from the _objListofData array.
See the below example you will get idea about this.

```js
var _objListofData = [{Code: 1},{Code: 2},{Code: 2}, {Code: 1},{Code: 2},{Code: 3}]
_objListofData = _objListofData.reduce(function (item, e1) {
                var matches = item.filter(function (e2) { return e1.Code == e2.Code });
                if (matches.length == 0) {
                    item.push(e1);
                }
                return item;
            }, []);
console.log(_objListofData);
```

Comment: It would be more instructive if you explained how it works, not just what the result is. I did that in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be filtering out duplicates in the array based on the `Code` property. A more intuitive way of doing this could be:

```
const uniqueMap = _objListofData.reduce((map, item) => {
    if (!map.has(item.Code)) {
        map.set(item.Code, item);
    }
    return map;
}, new Map());
const uniques = Array.from(uniqueMap.values());
```

The code "reduces" the array into a single map. If it encounters a key seen before it is discarded. Finally, it grabs the list of `values` for the unique keys from the `Map`.

Comment: Now the OP has a second problem, how is this code working :P

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.
**Here is some advice:**

1. Don't use reduce, use other things. It is hard, even for experienced
   devs, to understand a code that contains 'reduce'.
2. Use type definition (TypeScript), it will help you and your team in a
   long run.
3. Bonus. If you do need to use reduce (or any hard to understand code)
   put an example input and output as a comment!

**Analyzing the type of the input**

I think, `_objListOfData` is an array of object which had a
`Code` property on it, and its value is a `number`. Something
like this:

```
[ 
  { Code: 1 }, 
  { Code: 15 }, 
  { Code: 17 }, 
  { Code: 90 } 
]
```

**Summary**

The code goals is to remove any recurring object with the same
`Code`. So for example, from this:

`[{Code: 1}, {Code: 5}, {Code: 2}, {Code: 1}]`

into this:

`[{Code: 1}, {Code: 5}, {Code: 2}]`

**Step by step understanding**

1. Reduce accept two parameters, it is the function and initialValue.
2. In your case, the initialValue is an empty array `[]`.
3. In your case, the function is this guy:

```
function(item, e1) {
  var matches = item.filter(function(e2) {
    return e1.Code == e2.Code
  });
  if (matches.length == 0) {
    item.push(e1);
  }
  return item;
}
```

The value of `item` will start from the initialValue you passed, after one iteration, this value will be passed to the next iteration. The value of `e1` will be each of the item inside of the `_objListofData` array.

1. In the first iteration, `item` will have the value of
   [] and the `e1` will have the value of an item
   inside your array, say (for example) it is `{ Code: 1 }`.
   Then, it will go to the filter the empty array you give, searching for
   any item with the same code, if anything matches, it will be returned
   to the `var matches`. Then, it checks the length of
   `matches`, if its equals zero, then there is no match,
   hence the item is unique and we want them in our resulting array. Last,
   you want to return `item` so that it will be passed into
   the next iteration.
2. In the second iteration, we have `item` equals `[ { Code: 1} ]`. Then, say our next item is `{ Code: 2 }`. Then the
   filter will works again, but nothing match, so the value
   `{ Code: 2 }` will be pushed to the `item` array
   again.
3. In the third iteration, we have `item` equals `[ { Code: 1 }, { Code: 2 } ]`. Then, say our next item is `{ Code: 1 }`.
   This time, the filter will cancel out this value, so this value will
   not be pushed into the `item` array. Hence our
   `item` value still holds at
   `[ { Code: 1 }, { Code: 2 } ]`.

You can definitely check the comprehensive guid here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce